# Android Web app automation : Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: appium

I am trying to automate webapps on Android devices using appium.

Configuration:

Appium:V1.3.7

Android version 5.0

Code :

```
AndroidDriver dr;
WebDriverWait myWaitVar;

    DesiredCapabilities capa = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capa.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
        capa.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        capa.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capa.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");

        try {
            dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capa);
            System.out.println("in the session");
            dr.get("www.google.com");

    }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error : 
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","origValue":"connect ECONNREFUSED"},"sessionId":null}

Attaching Appium logs with this post.
Please help

Comment: Please try to add some waiting time before dr.get. The problem may occurs because appium still not ready for the communication with the device.

Comment: Thanks Eugene...I will try this. Does this problem occur in case there is some issue with Appium/Chrome Driver/Chrome browser in the smartphone i am using ? what do you think ?

Comment: No I don't think this device related issue.

Comment: I tried the way you said. ...introducing some wait before dr.get..but not working :(

Comment: Are you sure that Chrome installed on your device?

Comment: yes it is..i can see package "com.android.chrome" in the adb list packages

Comment: Please see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9fmf9Ka6Zw)

Comment: Still the same error..ECONNREFUSED... :(

Comment: Hi Eugene,
I am now getting different logs.
Recentaly i upgraded Appium to 1.4.0 .

but still no success. Error is " info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)","origValue":"Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED"},"sessionId":null}"

Comment: Do you want upload your project to github and I try to help?

Comment: @Eugene : either ways.